Executing query against prepopulated database in React native for my android device is returning undefined
Trying to get list from an existed table (Nouns) in prepopulated database of my react native project but it is returning undefined.
I have added the prepopulated database in :
Android: android/app/src/main/assets/DictionaryG.db database location for android
for IOS i just created a new assets folder on the root project and added the database file within it
ReactNative version: v0.74.3
When I run the same query on SQLite browser i get the result in image Sql query results in SQlite browser
Here is how my code looks but the value of nouns is undefined
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';




 export const getVerbs = () =>{
    const [nouns, setNouns] = useState([]);

    const db = SQLite.openDatabase({
        name: 'DictionaryG.db',
        createFromLocation: 1
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        db.transaction((tx) => {
          tx.executeSql('SELECT Definition FROM Nouns limit 1',
          [],
          (tx, results) => {
            var temp = [];
            console.log(results)
            for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; ++i)
              temp.push(results.rows.item(i));
            setNouns(temp);
          });
        });
      }, [])

      
      return nouns;
    
}

Any help will be appreciated
I have tried to create the DB globally also tried to use only
const results = db.executeSql('SELECT Definition FROM Nouns limit 1',
still the value is undefined
